# import a class and implement a function in Android

Tags: android, class, import

i'm creating an App preferences class that i can put functions in that i use app wide such as a check internet connection function. what i'm trying to do is import the class into my activity the run one its functions in the on create. does anyone know how to do this?

heres what i've got so far

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import co.myapp.AppPreferences;

public class Loading extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lo_loading);
        AppPreferences.class.checkInternet()
    }
}
```

heres my AppPreferences.java

```
public class AppPreferences {


public void checkInternet(){

    Log.v("Pref", "checking internet");

}   

}
```

Comment: Make object of AppPreferences and call with help it's method checkInternet.

Comment: This is not an android specific problem its a java related problem. @LukeBatley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checkInternet()` is non-static you need an instance of `AppPreferences` in your activity and use the method on this instance:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lo_loading);
    AppPreferences appPrefs = new AppPreferences()
    appPrefs.checkInternet()
}
```

Another solution is to make `checkInternet()` `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate an object of type Apppreference in order to access its methods (unless they are static)